# Unity 2.0: Why does BuildUp() check constructor?

Tags: unity-container, instance, code-injection

Can someone help me to solve the problem, please.

I'm trying to add an instance of the class SeviceImpl which has two constructors and dependency.

Below is what I get.

- In the Variant A the unity doesn't inject dependency. I thought it
  would.
- In the Variant B I don't understand why the BuildUp() method needs to
  check constructors when object already exists? Why can't it just
  inject dependencies?

  ```
  public interface IService
  {
      void Run();
  }

  public class Database
  {
  }

  public class ServiceImpl : IService
  {
      public ServiceImpl(int i)
      {}

      public ServiceImpl(bool b)
      { }

      [Dependency]
      public Database Db { get; set; }

      public void Run()
      {}
  }

   public static void Main()
   {
          using (var unity = new UnityContainer())
          {
              unity.RegisterInstance<Database>(new Database());

              // Now I want to register an instance of ServiceImpl

              // Variant A

              unity.RegisterInstance<IService>(new ServiceImpl(3));
              var srv = unity.Resolve<IService>();
              // srv.Db is null which is bad
              unity.BuildUp(srv); // Doesn't throw an exception
              // srv.Db is still null

              // Variant B

              var srv = new ServiceImpl(3);
              // Hoping this call will inject Database
              unity.BuildUp(srv); // Now it does: InvalidOperationException - The type ServiceImpl has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
              unity.RegisterInstance<IService>(srv);
          }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In variant A you're registering an existing instance, so the container will not try to inject any additional dependencies.

In variant B, the container creates a delegate to create an instance and inject dependencies. This delegate is used both for creating new instances or injecting dependencies on a new instance, so if the container cannot figure out how to create an instance it will fail. You could argue that the container should set up the delegate to throw if it's used to create an instance but still allow build ups rather than fail to create the delegate, but that's how it works today.

You can work around this by registering the type to create instances using a specific constructor, but that might not be appropriate if you do not want the container to create new instances of this type, only to build up existing ones.

```
unity.RegisterType<ServiceImpl>(new InjectionConstructor(false));
```

Comment: Thank you, fsimonazzi. Hope it will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

@fsimonazzi's method worked, but unity will invoke `CreatePlan`:

```
IBuildPlanPolicy CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)
```

after `RegisterType`. It's a heavy operation.